# How to align these items?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a website, but I'm struggling with having a logo and ul on the same line

If you could also let me know what I did wrong, I'd really appreciate that.

What I want it to look like

[image]

What it currently looks like

[image]

```css
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  /* display: inline-flex; */
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <a id="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/128x90.png?text=XYZ">
    </a>
    <li>
      <a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Classes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: The only valid child of a list element is a list item. You can't have the logo anchor there. Set everything to `inline-block` and it should work.

Comment: Your commented flex rules imply that you'd like to use flexbox. Is that actually a priority?

Comment: I made you a proper [mcve] using stacksnippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the image out of the unordered list, as it's not part of the menu. Then give the header and the ul a display of flex, and vertically align the items with `align-items:center`. Finally, give the ul a `margin-left:auto`. In the context of Flexbox, this pushes it all the way to the right in its container.

```css
header, .main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo img{
    width: 100px;
}

.main-nav{
    margin-left: auto;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a id="logo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/128x90.png?text=XYZ">
  </a>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About Us</a></li>
    <li><a>Classes</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>News</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and it will work. Some rules:

1. Try to use `<ul> <li> <a>` not `<ul> <a> <li>`. So better keep logo out of `<ul>`
2. Close `</header>`
3. Use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` in `<header>`

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!--  logo -->
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/551/70/70.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--  nav -->
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Classes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep the image outside `<ul>` and enclose it in a div with `display:inline-flex`

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.main-nav {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.main-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a id="logo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/128x90.png?text=XYZ">
  </a>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Classes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```